# Resource to bitmap conversion results in poor quality

Tags: android

I never really noticed it before but when I change the image of an imageview using setImageBitmap, using a bitmap which is decoded from resources using BitmapFactory, then the quality of image deteriorates and I don't know why.

I even played around with BitmapFactoryOptions like `options.inPreferredConfig`,    `options.inJustDecodeBounds`, `options.inDither`, but the results were pretty much the same; a poor quality image.

On the other if I just use setImageResource, the image doesn't deteriorates and is in best quality possible.

So basically these two codes

1. `Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.keypad,options);                           iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.keypad))`
2. `iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.messages);`

results in different image quality.

Can anybody explain why? And how to solve this quality issue using code 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have blurry images using the `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` method, you can use this code:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), path, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.keypad));
```

Setting the `inScaled` parameter of `BitmapFactory.Options` class to false, will prevent blurry images on low screen resolutions since it will prevent scalling as mentioned in the answer of [this previous SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822358/1482726) Maybe you have already tried this but i thought worth mentioning.