# My imageview Android Are Blurry I don't get why

Tags: android, image, imageview, blurry

I  am displaying picture with a classical Imageview from the Android SDK but the picture are Blurry.
I don't get why here is the snippet from the  layout

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

And for the ImageLoader I use this class

```
package com.lordalexworks.zweet.controller.helper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.lordalexworks.zweet.R;

public class ImageLoader {

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public String url;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    ExecutorService executorService;

    FileCache fileCache;

    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inScaled = false;
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inScaled = false;
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

}
```

I think maybe it should be the options but it doesn't work. 
and this o.inScaled = false;
o2.inScaled = false; 
I get the hint from here [Bad image quality after resizing/scaling bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap)