# Creating Bitmap on the fly in android and share it using Intent without losing quality

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap

I'm using below code for taking a view as parameter and create a bitmap from it:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
}
```

Now I'm using this code for taking screen shot from specific view and share it using Intent:

```
Bitmap captured = commons.screenShot(view);
String pathofBmp = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), captured,"title", null);
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent1.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent1, "Share image using"));
```

It works perfect. But the result is a image with black background and low quality.
I've searched a lot, for example [this way(Bad image quality after resizing/scaling bitmap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap?answertab=votes#tab-top), But problem still exists.
Any idea?
Thank in advanced.

Comment: If insertImage() lowers the quality of the picture then why not save the bitmap to file yourself? Further i would like to know what you consider to be the result in 'the result is an image..'. Where does one see the result?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to save file, I just need to create bitmap on the fly.