# Scale image without losing image quality did not work

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bitmapimage

Does anyone know how to scale the bitmap image without losing the image quality ? Currently I facing this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315387/will-the-image-too-big-caused-app-return-to-previous-activity), where the size of selected image maybe too big caused the app return to another activity.

So now I tried using this method to scale the selected image without losing its quality. I get the code from [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.my/2012/10/android-how-to-scale-bitmap-and-retain.html).

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                    null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    Bitmap a = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    photo = scaleBitmap(a, 200, 200);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }
                break;
}

  public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        float scaleX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
        float scaleY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
        float pivotX = 0;
        float pivotY = 0;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotX, pivotY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```

The answer seems helpful for most of the people, but why it doesn't work for me ? Have I missed anything?

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaGsn.jpg)

[selected image display on imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGAuZ.jpg)

Comment: if you wan to scale it to the size 200 x 200, most likely you will get distorted image, since original image is not square one

Comment: @pskink where can  I know the original size ?

Comment: by reading `Bitmap` docs?

Comment: @pskink what value should I put instead of 200,200 ..still stuck !

Comment: did you read `Bitmap` docs? do you now know what is the size of your `Bitmap`? if so, just make it smaller

Comment: @pskink but the image does not fixed.

Comment: i have no green idea what you mean

Comment: @pskink if make it smaller, the scaled image will not losing its quality ?

Comment: of course it will loose its quality, if you want to preserve original quality, dont scale it

Comment: @pskink if I don't scale it, I will get this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315387/will-the-image-too-big-caused-app-return-to-previous-activity)

Comment: I've been looking the answer for two days and yet still can't find the solution

Comment: then scale down your image if you have OutOfMemory problems

Comment: @pskink How do I make the image scaled efficiency?

Comment: search the web, 20 seconds search gives: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) what were you doing for two days?

Comment: I'm sure you have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315387/will-the-image-too-big-caused-app-return-to-previous-activity) before comment right ?

Comment: @pskink seems like I only can have one of these two methods :'(

Comment: @pskink I want to resize the selected image without loosing its quality.  If I use `scaleBitmap` (stated as my post ), image looked blur.  If I use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315387/will-the-image-too-big-caused-app-return-to-previous-activity) method, the size of image too large...

Comment: While I'm fairly certain there are many ways to implement this automatically based on your image size and canvas size, you can of course just play around with the settings manually.
instead of the code line: photo = scaleBitmap(a, 200, 200)
try photo = scaleBitmap(a, 100, 200) for instance.
Fiddle around with the numbers until it looks like you want it to.

Comment: @Uvar but the image still look blur

Comment: I'm afraid it's never possible to preserve full quality, since your visual information just does not fit onto the small canvas. It should be doable to render it slightly blurred, yet readable though

Comment: @uvar is this the only method to scale bitmap image without loosing its quality?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
public Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,int newWidth,int newHeight) {    
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

    float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
    float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, middleX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: Ratio of required height and width should match the ratio on previous height width
like: initial height=100 width=300 then if req height is 200 then width should be 600

Comment: so in my case should be 600, 200?

Comment: Can you share current height and width of image, and required too ?

Comment: You mean the imageView ?

Comment: no, I mean actual size of image which you need to scale

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98152/discussion-between-seng-and-mobile-apps-expert).

Comment: app crashed `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try this for scaling bitmap

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    float scaleX = ((float)newWidth) /  bitmap.getWidth();
    float scaleY = ((float)newHeight) / bitmap.getHeight(); 
    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.postScale(scaleX, scaleY);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() , scaleMatrix, true);
    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this it will definitely help you to reduce the size without loosing quality.
public Bitmap compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = imageUri;
        // String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not
        // loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
        // you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

        // max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as
        // 816x612

        /*
         * float maxHeight = 816.0f; float maxWidth = 612.0f;
         */
        float maxHeight = 1080.0f;
        float maxWidth = 800.0f;

        float imgRatio = actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        // width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the
        // image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        // setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of
        // the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

        // inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        // this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low
        // on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            // load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        // check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }

            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename(filePath);
        // File image = new File(getFilename(), System.currentTimeMillis() +
        // ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            // write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by
            // filename.
            boolean didWrite = scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

            out.close();

            System.out.println(didWrite);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return scaledBitmap;

    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public String getFilename(String originalname) {

        ImageCache imageCache = new ImageCache(this);
        File file = new File("Your folder path");

        // return file;
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "F_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        return uriSting;

    }
```

Comment: where are your ImageCache?

Comment: There is no need to use the image Cache

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not keeping the aspect ratio of the original image.
in your code if you need the width to be 200, then the height should be calculated like this:

```
newHeight = ((float) originalHeight/(float) originalWidth) * (float) newWidth;
```

So in your case:

```
float newHeight = ((float) a.getHeight()/(float) a.getWidth()) * (float) 200;
```

And then call your scaling function with `width:200` and height calculated from original value.

After that if the quality is still low, then experiment with increasing the width and stop when you get the needed quality.

Answer (score -1):

While you have too much large image at that time you must Required to manage Bitmap cache policy.Bitmap cache management is too much Complex.So in Android we have one superb library [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).this library is provide inbuilt cache management. this will be manage your bitmap in background and it's also provide image cache feature.once your image is load and again you load this same Image this will be get in cache.it's inbuilt functionality no need to change in code.

I hope you are clear with my solution.
Best of Luck