# How do you deal with insanely high MP cameras (and images) on Android? - "Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap"

Tags: android, image, kotlin, canvas, camera

I have an activity where the user can open the camera like so

```
getPictureUri(createImageFromFile = true)?.let {
        photoUri = it
        openCameraActivity(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE, it)
    } ?: photoViewModel.onRequestUriError()
```

openCamera is an Activity Extension that looks like this

```
fun Activity.openCameraActivity(requestCode: Int, pictureUri: Uri) {
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
    takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri)
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode)
    }
}
```

}

We write the image to a file when we get it back, and store the photoUri in the app somewhere. It works great! The issue is that some users have super high megapixel cameras, like 64mp, and when they take a picture it tries to display in the UI and it crashes.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: co.app.staging, PID: 27859
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(256576512bytes) bitmap.
```

Is there a way I can limit the camera resolution on this? I could turn the quality down but that seems like a bandaid at best. What are some decent solutions for this?

Comment: Consider using something like https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view that can handle high-resolution images.

Comment: It is more than just displaying it, I do not want to store insanely large images as well. Anything past 1080p is way more than I need.

Comment: "I do not want to store insanely large images as well" -- then do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Use the camera APIs, either directly or via a wrapper library (CameraX, FotoApparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.).

Comment: Did not know about CameraX, let me give this a shot

Comment: @RohanHarrison, Did you try out CameraX. If so did it solve your problem? I am running into a similar issue when using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way to draw bitmap on canvas from `URI`, try this:

(Explanation given below code)

```
private void drawBitmapUriOnCanvas(Uri selectedImage) {
    if (selectedImage != null) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    selectedImage), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                            selectedImage), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            Bitmap alteredBitmap;
            if (bmp != null) {
                if (getDeviceRam(this) <= 1024) {
                    bmp = getResizedBitmap(bmp, displayWidth);
                }
                bmp = checkAndRotateBitmap(bmp);
                alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp
                        .getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

                (now alteredBitmap is processed bitmap and you can use it)
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading Image Metadata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Other included methods:

```
public static long getDeviceRam(Context context) {
    ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
    long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem;
    long fileSizeInKB = totalMemory / 1024;
    // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
    return fileSizeInKB / 1024;
}

public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Here, first of all i decoded image uri using `BitmapFactory`, then i checked device ram and it it was of 1GB then i resize the bitmap other wise original bitmap will be ok for next step,

And next was simply drawing bitmap on canvas and you will get `alteredBitmap` will is processed bitmap and it will be easy to use.

If this will not work then there is another option for completing your requirement and it was given below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromGallery(selectedImage.getPath(), 800, 800);

private Bitmap getBitmapFromGallery(String path, int width, int height) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // if you use image from camera then in some cases it will rotated automatically like it was captured landscape but displays portrait then you have to use method `checkAndRotateBitmap()` which was also given below
    //    bitmap = checkAndRotateBitmap(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

private Bitmap checkAndRotateBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    try {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imgPath);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap;

        switch (orientation) {

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotatedBitmap = Helper.rotateImage(bmp, 90);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotatedBitmap = Helper.rotateImage(bmp, 180);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotatedBitmap = Helper.rotateImage(bmp, 270);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            default:
                rotatedBitmap = bmp;
        }
        return rotatedBitmap;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

## EDIT

for more information on how `getBitmapFromGallery()` method works, you should have look at https://medium.com/android-news/loading-large-bitmaps-efficiently-in-android-66826cd4ad53

That's all my friend, now try one of the methods for your requirement and let me know if this will work or not, also help me improve my answer if anything was wrong..Thank you!!